# Package And inheritance Concept in java

Tags: java

I have define package p1 and class protected in it. Now i have defined package p2 and class protected2 extends p1.protected but it is showing p1does not exist

Comment: It's much simpler to assist with code rather than a sentence

Comment: Did you add an `import` statement in the source file for class `protected2`? Classes that are in a different package must be imported.

Comment: First of all stick to Java naming conventions where you capitalize the first letter of the class name. And protected is not a valid class name.

You can only extend public classes from other packages. Is the class protected1 in package p1 a public class?

Comment: @Jesper - Not necessary. You don't need to import them as long as you use the full package name like he mentioned p1.protected1

Answer (score 0):

How it will show as available if it is in another packageP1 and it is **protected**? Check with your access modifiers concept and inheritance again.

a protected class cannot be inherited again into a class of diffrerent package. It applies only for basic package